# Primefaces: How to add icon and <p:badges> inside <p:submenu> on Panel Menu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

As title stated, I want to put icon and badge beside the title of submenu of Panel Menu. However, Primefaces' submenu default icon is the expand arrow/triangle. When I do this:

```
 <p:badge value="2">
        <p:submenu icon="pi pi-envelope">
 </p:badge>
```

It will prompt error, and doing vice versa like wrapping badge and closing using </p:submenu> is impossible because there are menuitems also. Not to mention the icon is not showing.

So, can I really achieve this using free open source provided? Or this is exclusive to paid user only?
[Example from Primefaces template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nps3Y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges are not supported on (sub)menu items at this moment (PrimeFaces 11). No matter if you use a free or paid theme. The only component that currently supports a badge on a child node is [`p:speedDial`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/speedDial.xhtml). What you can do is [open a feature request](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new?assignees=&labels=new+feature&template=feature_request.md&title=Component%3A+Title) and if possible submit a pull request.

See also:

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7898
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7922